# How to "refill" worker queue in python after an exception?

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium

I'm trying to build a multithreading selenium scraper. Let's say I want to get 100.000 websites and print their page sources, using 20 ChromeDriver instances. By now, I have the following code:

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
from selenium import webdriver
from numpy.random import randint


selenium_data_queue = Queue()
worker_queue = Queue()

# Start 20 ChromeDriver instances
worker_ids = list(range(20))
selenium_workers = {i: webdriver.Chrome() for i in worker_ids}
for worker_id in worker_ids:
    worker_queue.put(worker_id)


def selenium_task(worker, data):

    # Open website
    worker.get(data)
    
    # Print website page source
    print(worker.page_source)

def selenium_queue_listener(data_queue, worker_queue):

    while True:
        url = data_queue.get()
        worker_id = worker_queue.get()

        worker = selenium_workers[worker_id]
        
        # Assign current worker and url to your selenium function
        selenium_task(worker, url)
        
        # Put the worker back into the worker queue as  it has completed it's task
        worker_queue.put(worker_id)
        data_queue.task_done()
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    selenium_processes = [Thread(target=selenium_queue_listener,
                                 args=(selenium_data_queue, worker_queue)) for _ in worker_ids]

    for p in selenium_processes:
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()
    
    # Adding urls indefinitely to data queue
    
    # Generating random url just for testing
    for i in range(100000):
        d = f'http://www.website.com/{i}'
        selenium_data_queue.put(d)
    
    # Wait for all selenium queue listening processes to complete
    selenium_data_queue.join()
    
    # Tearing down web workers
    for b in selenium_workers.values():
        b.quit()
```

My question is: if any ChromeDriver abruptly shuts down (i.e. non-recoverable exception like `InvalidSessionIdException`), is there a way to remove it from the worker queue and insert a new ChromeDriver in its place, so that I still have 20 usable instances? If so, there's a good pratice to accomplish it?